# How to handle popup authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, web-scraping, http-authentication

I'm fairly new to this, and don't have anyone else to ask. I'm attempting to access a webpage programmatically (C#) for some web-scraping software. I've figured out the process of using the HttpWebResponse and HttpWebRequest classes to perform a login through a web page form, but I have a website which has a two stage login procedure.

The first login occurs via a pop-up. No webpage is loaded in the background, just a pop-up dialog saying authentication is required and prompts for a username and password.

After getting past the first login, the second login is simply a web form which I should be able to handle myself from what I've already learned.

My question: How do I programmatically provide the login information for the pop-up authentication request?

EDIT

Just to provide some more information. Fiddler gives the Host as CONNECT when attempting to access the website.

EDIT

I attempted to use MrEye's answer below, and though it seemed to get me a little further, still having hangups. I was gettin certificate issues, so after some Google work I found a workaround for it by adding the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        };
```

Now I'm getting a `System.Net.WebException` with the value "The remove server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." The exception's `Status` is ProtocolError, though I haven't been able to get any further. I know for certain that the username/password being provided are valid.

Comment: The 401 HTTP response indicates that the remote server has rejected the credentials you have submitted to it  I know you said that you are certain they are correct, how certain is certain ;).  Could you post the code for the HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is asign a NetworkCredential object to the Credentials property of the HttpWebRequest object you have created.  For example:

```
myWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
```

Depending on the server you are connecting to you may also need:

```
myWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: Finally got it to work, it didn't have anything to do with the credentials I was providing, they were correct, but I needed to allow redirect and the URL was slightly incorrect. Thanks a ton!